# Polymorphically find model from database in Yii2

Tags: php, database, model-view-controller, polymorphism, yii2

I have one table in the database(mysql). But this table stores several slightly different types of rows. The type depends on this tables's `type` column. I have an abstract ActiveRecord class for a table and several descendant subclasses implementing slightly different logic for the rows of the same table of different types. Now I am implementing an update controller action for all the types of rows. I am provided with an id of the row and need to create an ActiveRecord instance representing the row with this id. But I somehow need to create instances of different subclasses depending on the type of the corresponding row.

If I were provided with both a type and an id I could've used a factory to pick a corresponding subclass. But I can already have the type in the database and an id gives me enough information to pick it from there. But if I were to pick the type from the database first and then to create an instance of the corresponding subclass that would've meant executing the same query twice.

I want to find a good way to get the data from the database and then pick a right ActiveRecord subclass to create an instance for it without making excessive queries or requiring excessive data. Is there a way to do it Yii2?

Or should I approach this problem somehow differently? The actual problem is having several almost the same but a bit different entities stored in a single table with a bit different business-logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of approaches to this problem is called "Single table inheritance" and described by Martin Fowler [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html). There is also good article about its implementation in Yii 2 in **samdark**'s (one of the main Yii 2 contributors) cookbook, which is currently in process of writing but is available on [Github](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/ar-single-table-inheritance.md).

I'm not going to copy the whole article, but leaving just link is also not enough. Here are some important things:

**1)** Create common query for all types of objects (for example cars):

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveQuery;

class CarQuery extends ActiveQuery {
    public $type;

    public function prepare($builder)
    {
        if ($this->type !== null) {
            $this->andWhere(['type' => $this->type]);
        }
        return parent::prepare($builder);
    }
}
```

**2)** Create separate model for each type (extending from common model Car):

*Sport cars:*

```
namespace app\models;

class SportCar extends Car
{
    const TYPE = 'sport';

    public static function find()
    {
        return new CarQuery(get_called_class(), ['type' => self::TYPE]);
    }

    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        $this->type = self::TYPE;
        return parent::beforeSave($insert);
    }
}
```

*Heavy cars:*

```
namespace app\models;

class HeavyCar extends Car
{
    const TYPE = 'heavy';

    public static function find()
    {
        return new CarQuery(get_called_class(), ['type' => self::TYPE]);
    }

    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        $this->type = self::TYPE;
        return parent::beforeSave($insert);
    }
}
```

**3)** Override `instantiate()` method in `Car` model to return correct type of cars:

```
public static function instantiate($row)
{
    switch ($row['type']) {
        case SportCar::TYPE:
            return new SportCar();
        case HeavyCar::TYPE:
            return new HeavyCar();
        default:
           return new self;
    }
}
```

Then you can use any type of cars individually as regular models.

Comment: So overriding `instantiate` lets me choose from the different ActiveRecord subclasses according to the data retrieved from the database. That is exactly what I was asking about! That way I won't need to provide the type to my controller when working with the already existing row.  Great thanks!

Comment: `instantiate` is hard to type-check in Psalm. Might be better to use a separate factory class instead.