# Authenticating against two different database tables

Tags: php, yii2

I'm a little bit confused about the authentication procedure in Yii 2.0. I'm developing a web application that has two kind of users (students and lecturers). Each entity has its own database table (MySQL if that matters) with its own id, username and password fields. I've looked at the advanced application template which includes authentication against database, but in that case, the user table is unique. In my case, I must be able to determine which database table to look for the user record (student or lecturer). The Identity interface:

```
interface IdentityInterface
{
    /**
    * Finds an identity by the given ID.
    * @param string|integer $id the ID to be looked for
    * @return IdentityInterface the identity object that matches the given ID.
    * Null should be returned if such an identity cannot be found
    * or the identity is not in an active state (disabled, deleted, etc.)
    */
    public static function findIdentity($id);
    /**
    * Finds an identity by the given token.
    * @param mixed $token the token to be looked for
    * @param mixed $type the type of the token. The value of this parameter depends on the implementation.
    * For example, [[\yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth]] will set this parameter to be `yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth`.
    * @return IdentityInterface the identity object that matches the given token.
    * Null should be returned if such an identity cannot be found
    * or the identity is not in an active state (disabled, deleted, etc.)
    */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null);
    /**
    * Returns an ID that can uniquely identify a user identity.
    * @return string|integer an ID that uniquely identifies a user identity.
    */
    public function getId();
    /**
    * Returns a key that can be used to check the validity of a given identity ID.
    *
    * The key should be unique for each individual user, and should be persistent
    * so that it can be used to check the validity of the user identity.
    *
    * The space of such keys should be big enough to defeat potential identity attacks.
    *
    * This is required if [[User::enableAutoLogin]] is enabled.
    * @return string a key that is used to check the validity of a given identity ID.
    * @see validateAuthKey()
    */
    public function getAuthKey();
    /**
    * Validates the given auth key.
    *
    * This is required if [[User::enableAutoLogin]] is enabled.
    * @param string $authKey the given auth key
    * @return boolean whether the given auth key is valid.
    * @see getAuthKey()
    */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey);
}
```

contains the `findIdentity()` method which unfortunately is static. I'm saying this because I have trouble passing an extra parameter or accessing a instance variable from the `app\models\User` class that implements this interface and that will differentiate the database table for the user authentication. The `$id` parameter in `findIdentity()` in my case is **not** unique.

How can I find a solution about this?

Comment: Is the structure of `students` and `lecturers` table absolutely different? Maybe just use the common table `users` with `type` column? You can use different models for them if needed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29167761/polymorphically-find-model-from-database-in-yii2/29170849#29170849 Otherwise I think you should solve this with overriding framework classes (which are responsible for that) since it's non-common and widespread approach.

Comment: I guess this would be a solution, to have the same table for all users, since both contain the basic fields (id, username, password) and have different tables for each user type fields. But I'd like a solution a bit cleaner than this. How would I implement authentication against two different tables?

Comment: I mean non-widespread approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 3 options:

**1)** If the structure of `students` and `lecturers` tables is no absolutely different, maybe it's better to use the common table `users` with `type` column. You can use different models for them if needed (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29167761/polymorphically-find-model-from-database-in-yii2/29170849#29170849)).

**2)** Since it's non-common and non-widespread approach, you can override core classes.

Create copy of `IdentityInterface` with different namespace and change `findIdentity()` declaration to fit your needs. Then use your custom interface instead of built-in one.

Except `User` model don't forget to search all framework classes for usage of `findIdentity()` and replace it with your implementation.

As I see it's only called in `yii\web\User` in `loginByCookie()` and `renewAuthStatus()` protected methods.

Also override this class and then switch class in `user` component config to your custom one.

**3)** Pass additional parameters in some other ways. For example with `Yii::$app->params`. Seems like a hacking solution though.

Personally I recommend using first or third approach (in case you are against of using the first one).

Comment: After some more consideration, solution No. 1 is the way to go. Thank you.

Comment: I think you made right choice, it's definetely better in my opinion.

Comment: Could you provide an example regarding solution No. 2?

Comment: What exactly you need to know? I tried to mention all important details of that approach.

Comment: If I try to create a new interface that extends `yii\web\IdentityInterface` and try to override the `findIdentity()` static method, I get the PHP error: `Declaration must be compatible with IdentityInterface::findIdentity(id : int|string)` if I try to add new parameters. Since this method is static I cannot refer to interface variables in a non-static manner, which is the issue I guess. Any recommendations?

Comment: Yes, that's why I corrected my answer, you should create non-inherited copy and change that, I can't imagine better method for that right now.

Comment: Also you need to find and replace usages of built-in interface.to your custom one. I also mentioned where it's used (after global search through all framework classes).